# XPages - Value Picker - Update Multiple fields

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-extlib

I would like to use a dominoViewValuePicker to update several fields with several values. I have seen that it is possible to add multiple values to the one field. Is it possible to select one document from a dominoViewValuePicker and then use multiple values from this document to update multiple fields on the XPage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. Just set the onChange event to refresh those fields (preferably, they all go into a panel so that you can do a partial refresh rather than a full refresh) and compute the values (either from the script on the onChange or just by the formulas for determining those values in the first place).

If you do set up a panel for a partial refresh, make sure to give the panel an ID. By default panels are not given ID's and are not available to refresh.

Comment: Just make sure to give the panel an ID. By default panels are not given ID's and are not available to refresh.

Comment: Adding that to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I think my head exploded when I found that one out... I was thinking to myself, its a real shame that I can't refresh an entire table or panel because it doesn't have an ID, but I can give it an ID I wonder... KaBoooom... Now I'm refreshing everything like a madman